# find $B$ and $C$ with $BA=AC=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

**For**

$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1  \\
4 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}
$

find $B$ and $C$ with $BA=AC=\{0\}$.

---

I can put $C=A^{-1}\cdot \{0\}$ and $B=\{0\} \cdot A^{-1}$. But I have problems to find $A^{-1}$ because it is not linear independent. Any hint?

Comment: What do you mean with $\{0\}$?

Comment: @sigmabe I believe that's shorthand for a 3x3 matrix that's all zeros.

Comment: You can't find $A^{-1}$,because $A$ isn't invertible..

Comment: Why can't you just have 0 matrix for B and C?

Comment: You were probably expected (if not instructed) to find $3\times 3$ matrices $B,C$ that are nonzero to satisfy $BA = AC = 0$.  The fact that $A$ is not invertible is precisely what allows us to find such nonzero matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\ker A$ is non trivial and $v=(1,1,-3)^T \in \ker A$, hence
$C = v (1,...,1)^T$ satisfies $AC = 0$.

Since $\ker A$ is non trivial, it follows that $\ker A^T$ is non trivial,
and we can find $u = (2,-1,0)^T \in \ker A^T$, hence wth
$B=(1,...,1) u^T$, we have $BA = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

For $C$ you must chose the columns out of $ker(A)$ and for $B$ you must chose the rows out of $ker(A^T)$, because then $A^TB^T=0$ and so $BA=(A^TB^T)^T=0$.

For the simplest solution take $B=C=0$.